# Is there a way to fetch rows using cursors in PostgresSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-function, database-cursor

This is my first time learning cursors. I have two tables: `drink d` and `cart c`. They both contain a common primary key where `c.did = d.did`. (where `did` = drink id). I'm trying to take the `teatype` from joining both rows so that I can update the stock of the `teatype`. For example, if it returns:

```
-----------
| teatype|
-----------
Oolong
Green Tea
Oolong
```

Then I would loop through that record so that I can update the stock of that specific `teatype` in the other table `tea` which contains the columns, `stock` where the `teatype` = the `teatype` of the cursor.

The issue I'm running into is not knowing how to correctly implement the cursor so that it can get looped through to update the stock. I've run into issues saying theres a `syntax error ar or near end` or at `if`. I've looked all over the web but can't find the correct resources.

I've tried putting the procedural statements within a function but that didn't help. It seems like I'm not on the right track and don't know how to approach this problem. My code is the following and I'm trying to run it in a PostgresSQL server.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foo()
RETURNS VOID AS $$

DECLARE
        tea_type RECORD;
        TeaCursor CURSOR FOR
                SELECT teatype FROM cart c
                JOIN drink d ON c.did = d.did;

Begin        

        OPEN TeaCursor;

        LOOP
        FETCH from TeaCursor into tea_type;
                exit when tea_type = null;

                UPDATE tea t
                        SET stock = stock - 1
                        WHERE t.type = tea_type.teatype;
                end if;
        END LOOP;

        close TeaCursor;
End;

$$LANGUAGE sql stable;
```

I should expect something like `UPDATE 1` or something that would say it has succesfully decremented the stock for that specific `teatype`. Instead I keep getting an error as such:

```
psql:test.sql:27: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "RECORD"
LINE 5:  tea_type RECORD;
```

Comment: The real question is why are you using an inefficient and slow cursor for that, when a single UPDATE statement without a loop would be a much better solution?

Answer (score 0):

You declared the function as `LANGUAGE sql` when really it is `LANGUAGE plpgsql`.